# Enum.IsDefined returns false for strings

Tags: c#, enums

I used the `Enum.IsDefined()` method for a string, but I get `False` in a situation where I think I should get `True`. Please check the below code:

```
public enum YourEnum : int
{
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1
}

public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(YourEnum), 1));
        Console.WriteLine(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(YourEnum), 1.ToString()));
    }
}
```

[**C# Fiddle Demo**](http://rextester.com/UMNE74342)
Result:

```
True
False
```

I don't know why should I get `False` in the second case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's `Enum.Parse()` that accepts `string`. `Enum.IsDefined()` is comparing the *constants* defined on your `enum` to what you're passing in.

Comment: In that answer yes that is not so related to my main question, actually `Enum.IsDefined` is accepting `object` as second parameter, I should ask that Do `IsDefined` also check the type of second parameter?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When you pass a string to the `IsDefined()` method, you are asking whether there is a value in the enum *having that name*. [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reads:

> The value parameter can be any of the following:
>   • Any member of type enumType.
>   • A variable whose value is an enumeration member of type enumType.
>   • **The string representation of the name of an enumeration member.** The characters in the string must have the same case as the enumeration member name.
>   • A value of the underlying type of enumType.

(emphasis mine)

It's a bit confusing to read, because the first, second, and fourth options above all result in the same thing: a value of the enum type being passed (boxed, of course).

But the third option is what's going on your scenario, and the string needs to match the *name* of an enum member. You're passing the string `"1"`, and the only valid names in the enum are `"Zero"` and `"One"`. The string `"1"` doesn't match either of those, so `IsDefined()` returns `false`.

Answer (score 8):

If you pass a string as an argument, it will look to see if one of the enum's names equals the specified string. Below will return true for both:

```
Console.WriteLine(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(YourEnum), 1));
Console.WriteLine(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(YourEnum), "Zero"));
```

See the [source code (line 1503)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,1503) for more. Having said that, it is better to deduce this information from the documentation as @Peter Duniho's answer has shown since the implementation can change: but nontheless, if you are curious the source code is there.